# Torricelli's Law with a Sphere (Ignore Mathematica part, already solved)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematica, wolfram-alpha

### Edit 1:

According to [this PDF](https://facultystaff.richmond.edu/~lwibberl/math212/DEProject.pdf), second page. The differential equation for a hemisphere becomes $$(r^2h-h^2) h' = -a^2\sqrt{2gh}$$

This differs from the equation I got, which looks like:

$$\pi(r^2-h^2)h'=-a^2\sqrt{2gh}$$

Are they equivalent for some reason, or did I do something wrong?

---

### Edit 2:

I tried out my equation, and I noticed that while $y(0) = 0.05\,m$ as I specified, I got that $y(1) \approx 0.15\,m$ which makes no sense, as the water level is supposed to decrease, not increase.

---

I want to calculate the volume of water inside a **half-sphere (hemisphere)** with a hole in the bottom of the sphere with an area $a = 5\times10^{-4}\,m^2$. The sphere has a radius $r = 0.05\,m$.

We have that $\frac{dV}{dt}=-a\sqrt{2g\cdot h(t)}$, where $V$ is volume, $g = 10\,ms^{-2}$, $h(t)$ is the height of the water level above the hole in the bottom of the **half-sphere**.

Using the second fundamental theorem of calculus, we have that

$$\frac{dV}{dh} = A(h) \implies A(h)\cdot h' = -a\sqrt{2g\cdot h}$$

Using the radius $r$ and the equation for circles we have:

$$x^2+h^2 = r^2 \iff x^2=r^2-h^2$$

As such, the area $A(t) = \pi(r^2-h^2)$. Our equation becomes:

$$\pi(r^2-(h(t))^2)h'(t) = -a\sqrt{2g\cdot h(t)}$$

And since it is an hemisphere, and we assume the water level starts at the top, we get the **initial value** $h(0) = r$.

---

Using **Wolfram|Mathematica** I tried entering the following:

> $\text{DSolve}\left[\left\{\pi  \left(0.05^2-y(t)^2\right) y'(t)=-0.0005 \sqrt{20 y(t)},y(0)=0.05\right\},y(t),t\right]$
>
> DSolve[{Pi (0.05^2 - (y[t])^2) y'[t] == -0.0005 Sqrt[20 y[t]], 
>     y[0] == 0.05}, y[t], t]

Output:

$\left\{y(t)\to \text{Root}\left[967062060875971906790400 \text{$\#$1}^5-24176551521899297669760 \text{$\#$1}^3+151103447011870610436 \text{$\#$1}-3061996020736000000 t^2-7.69564\times 10^{18} t-4.83531\times 10^{18}\&,1\right]\right\}$

My question is, what does this solution even mean? There were three more that looked identical. They make no sense when they have "$\#$" and the "$\&$" symbols attached *randomly*, **what do they mean?** And most of all, have I even done this correctly?

How would I use one of these solutions to figure out the volume at $t=120 \textbf{ seconds}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mathematica, $f(\#1, \#2, \dots)\&$ is an abbreviation of the function $(x_1, x_2, ...) \to f(x_1, x_2, \dots)$, and Root[$f$, $k$] returns the $k$th zero of a polynomial function $f(x)$. (I'm not sure how they're ordered.) Thus as a function of time, $y(t)$ satisifes some fifth-degree polynomial with coefficients depending on $t$. To get an explicit value at a given time $t_0$, just substitute $t_0$ for $t$ in the expression above and solve for $y$ via Root.

Comment: Ah. Using Root[...] I got a believable solution for $y$ :). There's just one more question I need answered (I edited my body text).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about that part, and don't have time right now to look over iit in detail. I'd be skeptical about a term like $(r^2 h - h^2)$, though, just for dimensional reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; however, I solved it by noticing $\frac{dV}{dh} \not= Area$ as it's a sphere, not a cylinder :).

Comment: @XMLParsing: Even better!